# How to start in daemon mode and suppress interactive dialogs?

Tags: emacs-daemon, gpg

I love to start emacs in daemon mode with my first login and then have the same emacs process for all subsequent logins, be it graphical, on physical console or from the network via ssh.

But there is a problem with this, when using a session to save the last open files and some of this files are encrypted (e.g. with gpg) and ask for the decryption key on load. Then the application is frozen and waits for an input from a disconnected *stdin*.

How can I defer the question to the first time interactively changing to the buffer?

Or, how can I exclude the encrypted files from the session?

And maybe there is just another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though having not found how to defer the password request, I have learned a lot about *desktops*.

So to exclude gpg-files from `desktop-save` there is the variable `desktop-files-not-to-save` that is documented

> Regexp identifying files whose buffers are to be excluded from saving.

The default value as shown in the customize buffer

```
\(^/[^/:]*:\|(ftp)$\)
```

excludes TRAMP files from being saved.  With the following regexp no files ending in `.gpg` are saved, too

```
\(^/[^/:]*:\|(ftp)$\)\|\(\.gpg$\)
```

and this is a first pragmatic answer to my problem.

Now I have to learn about the alternatives to *desktop mode* for [Session Management](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement).  Maybe there is something more clever ;-)